# VB.NET: is using Structures considered nasty?

Tags: vb.net

I use to use Structures quite a lot in the VB6 days, and try to avoid them now with .NET. Just wondering if using structures in 2010 instead of a Class is considered nasty?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I don't use them, but I certainly don't see anything wrong with using a struct.  It'll certainly be interesting to hear if anybody has any compelling reasons not to use them.

Comment: question doesn't show any research effort

Answer (score 17):

Choosing a `Structure` takes consideration instead of being inherently "nasty". There are reasons why a Structure *can* be nasty; however there are also reasons a `Class` can be nasty in its own way...

Basically when you decide between these two object oriented kinds of containers, **you're deciding how memory will be used.**

---

There are different semantics associated with `Structure` and `Class` in VB.NET and they represent different memory usage patterns.

By creating a `Class` you're creating a *reference type*.

- good for large data
- memory contains a reference to the object location on the heap (like the concept of pointing to an object) though happens transparently to the VB.NET programmer because you're in "managed mode".

By creating a `Structure` you're creating a *value type*.

- good for small data
- memory allocated contains the actual value
- be judicious because these are apt to get pushed on the stack area of memory (i.e. for local vars, but not class fields)  - too large and you could run into stack issues.

Also some good [video resources](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=reference+value+types&aq=f) on YouTube if you're an audio learner.

Many **articles** on the Internet like these MSDN articles to teach the basics and details:

- [Value Types and Reference Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs%28VS.80%29.aspx)
- [7.1 Types - Reference and Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711899%28VS.71%29.aspx)
- [MSDN Type Fundamentals - subheading: Reference and Value Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301569.aspx)

Example
[image]

Answer (score 6):

Structures exist because in some scenarios they make more sense than classes. They are particular useful for representing small abstract data types such as 3D points, latitude-longitude, rational numbers, etc.

The basic motivation for using structs is to avoid GC pressure. Since structs live inline (on the stack or inside whatever container you put them in) rather than on the heap, they typically result in far fewer small allocations, which makes a huge difference if you need to hold an array of one million points or rationals.

A key issue to watch out for is that structs are value types, and thus are generally passed around by value (the obvious exception being ref and out parameters). This has important implications. For instance:

```
Point3D[] points = ...;
points[9].Move(0, 0, 5);
```

The above code works fine, and increases the z coordinate of the 10th point by 5. The following code, however:

```
List<Point3D> points = ...;
points[9].Move(0, 0, 5);
```

Will still compile and run, but you will find that the z coordinate of the 10th point remains unchanged. This is because the List's index operator returns a copy of the point, and it is the copy that you are calling `Move` on.

The solution is quite simple. Always make structs immutable by marking all fields readonly. If you still need to `Move` points around, define + on the Point3D type and use assignment:

```
points[9] = points[9] + new Point3D(0, 0, 5);
```

Comment: Even beyond GC issues, exposed-field (mutable) structures are often the proper thing to use when the alternative would be to pass around groups of variables.  Something like `Drawing.Point` is, semantically, a pair of variables `X` and `Y`, and should logically be represented as an exposed-field struct (the fact that its members were wrapped in properties had side-effects which led to many people denouncing mutable structs as evil; such side-effects would not have occurred if it had simply exposed fields `X` and `Y`).  An exposed-field struct acts like a group of variables that...

Comment: ...can be passed around either singly or as a unit.  It's too bad that Microsoft's guidelines for deciding to use a struct suggest that one should only use a struct when representing something that has a single "value", when in fact the place structs offer the biggest win over classes is when representing things like `Point` which have multiple values that having meaning both individually and as a group (using separate variables would be clunky, and using a class would impose horrid semantics).

Comment: @supercat: All I got from Microsoft is [Classes and Structs (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173109.aspx): "Structs are best suited for small data structures that contain primarily data that is not intended to be modified after the struct is created." Exposed-field structs only prevent accidental mutation of fields belonging to temporaries; they don't magically make `List<Point3D>` elements mutable. Immutable structs achieve the same effect with the added bonus of preventing future accidents (i.e., a misguided maintainer adding setters or mutating methods).

Comment: I've read that, but am unclear what Microsoft would suggest for a data structure which should be piecewise mutable, but where members of the type *should have no identity outside the variable where they are stored*?  An exposed field struct has precisely those characteristics.  The implication that a desire to have something be piecewise mutable is a reason not to make it a struct makes no sense to me, since the only piecewise-mutable alternative to a struct would be a mutable class, which would in many cases be the *worst* kind of data type for such purposes.

Comment: Consider the read-write property `Graphics.Transform` of mutable class type `Matrix`, which in turn has a read-only property `Elements` of type `float[]`. Is there any means, other than by experimentation, by which one could determine whether modifying the array returned by `Elements` would effect the underlying `Matrix`, or whether modifying a `Matrix` would affect the `Graphics` from which it was received? If `Matrix` were an exposed-field struct, that fact  alone would make the semantics of `Graphics.Transform` crystal-clear, and would eliminate the need for `Elements`.

Comment: @supercat: The inability to const-qualify arrays is a (IMO deep) flaw in the language; one should generally avoid returning arrays, especially direct references to internal arrays. `Matrix.Elements` is a great example of why: the documentation gives no inkling as to whether the returned array is a reference to an actual inner array or a copy thereof. Why on earth didn't they just expose the Mij components directly, as they did for dx and dy? FWIW, I agree that `Matrix` probably should have been a struct, but it doesn't follow that it should have been an exposed-field struct.

Comment: If `Matrix` is an exposed-field struct, then it's clear how to change one or more aspects a `Graphics`'s `Transform` without affecting the others: read `Transform`, modify the appropriate items, and write it back.  While most struct properties exhibit value-type semantics, some do not; the indexer on `ArraySegment`, for example, does not access values from within the struct, but rather from an array which may be externally mutable.  Using an exposed-field struct makes it explicit that what one is accessing is indeed the information within the struct itself.

Comment: As for a lack of an immutable array type, I'm irked that such a thing *still* doesn't exist for any type other than `char` (`string` basically behaves like an `ImmutableArray<char>` should behave, but is of course limited to type `char`).  The problem goes somewhat deeper than that, though: for an immutable array type to be efficient, there needs to be a read-only-byref type; I think .net would have been a much better framework had such thing been included and verifiable.  To be sure, when marshalling between managed and unmanaged code, ...

Comment: ...one would have the same sort of need for const-casting that one is stuck with in C++, but not nearly as severely.  I think the designers of .net saw that managing const-correctness was a bother in C++, and thus regarded it as "evil", despite the fact that the workarounds for its absence were worse.  For example, when invoking a method on a readonly struct instance, the proper thing to do would be to pass a read-only-byref if the method can use one, or disallow the invocation if it can't.  Not only is passing a reference to a copy always slower than passing a direct reference...

Comment: ...but in cases where passing a direct reference would yield broken semantics, passing a reference to a copy will *also* yield broken semantics.  They'll be *different* broken semantics, and arguably less evil, but the extra copy operation will almost never yield correct semantics in cases where passing a direct reference would not have done so anyway.  (When marshalling to code which is declared to use a ref as read-only, but not verifiable as doing so, the marshalling layer could do a copy then; it should not be the default means of struct-member invocation, though)

Comment: @supercat: Updating `Transform` is even simpler if `Matrix` is immutable: assign a new value computed from the old. One rarely modifies matrices piecewise; much like `string`, they are atomic in that their operators predominantly work on the entire structure. Regarding `ArraySegment`: exposing an `Array` field would clarify what is returned, but even then only MSDN could say what it holds in the first place (original or copy).

Comment: It's very common to adjust the offset of a transform without affecting the scale, rotation, or shear.  It's somewhat common to scale or shift a transform in one dimension while leaving it unaffected in the other.  Having to copy all six parameters of a transform to perform any of these tasks when only two or three will be affected isn't particularly helpful.  There would be nothing to prevent an exposed-field `Matrix` struct from offering methods that would return a transformed matrix in cases where that would be convenient.  My point with `ArraySegment` was that...

Comment: ...while a value types' properties usually represent the state of the containing value type, they may represent the state of some outside object.  If `Matrix` were a struct with exposed fields `OffsetX`, `OffsetY`, etc. the statement `Matrix myMatrix = gr.Transform;` would clearly and unambiguously take a snapshot of those fields' values.  By contrast, if those things are properties, one might guess that they'd be snaphshots, but one wouldn't really know that they didn't represent a "live view" to the `Graphics` object which supplied the `Matrix`.

Answer (score 3):

It's considered pretty bad to use *anything* without understanding the implications.

Structures are [value types, not reference types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs%28VS.80%29.aspx) - and as such, they behave slightly differently.  When you pass a value type, modifications are on a copy, not on the original.  When you assign a value type to an `object` reference (say, in a non-generic list), [boxing](http://www.vbdotnetheaven.com/UploadFile/ggaganesh/BoxingUnboxingVbDotNet04202005004554AM/BoxingUnboxingVbDotNet.aspx) occurs.  Make sure you read up on the full effect of choosing one over the other.

Answer (score 3):

Read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289521%28VS.71%29.aspx) for some understanding benefits of structures vs classes and vice-versa.

> A structure can be preferable when:
>
> - You have a small amount of data and simply want the equivalent of the UDT
>       (user-defined type) of previous versions of Visual Basic
> - You perform a large number of operations on each instance and would incur
>       performance degradation with heap management
> - You have no need to inherit the structure or to specialize
>       functionality among its instances
> - You do not box and unbox the structure
> - You are passing blittable data across a managed/unmanaged boundary
>
> A class is preferable when:
>
> - You need to use inheritance and polymorphism
> - You need to initialize one or more members at creation time
> - You need to supply an unparameterized constructor
> - You need unlimited event handling support

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question directly, there is nothing inherantly wrong with using a structure in VB.NET. As with any design decision you do need to consider the consequences of this decision.

It's important that you're aware of the difference between a class and a structure so that you can make an educated decision about which is appropriate. As stated by Alex et al, one of the key differences between a structure and a class is that a structure is considered a value type and a class is considered a reference type.

Reference types use copy-by-reference sematics, this means that when an object is created or copied, only a pointer to the actual object is allocated on the stack, the actual object data is allocated on the heap.

In contrast, value types have copy-by-value sematics which means that each time a value type (e.g. a structure) is copied, then the entire object is copied to a new location on the stack/

For objects with a small amount of data, this isn't really a problem, but if you have a large amount of data then using a reference type will likely be less expensive in terms of stack allocations because only a pointer will be copied to the stack.

Microsoft [have guidelines on the use of structures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017.aspx) that more precisely describe the differences between classes and structures and the consequences of choosing one over the other

Answer (score 1):

From a behavioral standpoints, there are three types of 'things' in .net:

1. Mutable reference types

   Value types which can be mutated without being entirely replaced

   Immutable reference and value types

Eric Lippert really dislikes group #2 above, since .net isn't terribly good at handling them, and sometimes treats them as though they're in group #1 or #3.  Nonetheless, there are times when mutable value types make more sense semantically than would anything else.

Suppose, for example, that one has a rectangle and one wants to make another rectangle which is like the first one, but twice as tall.  It is IMHO cleaner to say:

```
  Rect2 = Rect1       ' Makes a new Rectangle that's just like Rect1
  Rect2.Height = Rect2.Height*2
```

than to say either

```
  Rect2 = Rect1.Clone  ' Would be necessary if Rect1 were a class
  Rect2.Height = Rect2.Height*2
```

or

```
  Rect2 = New Rectangle(Rect1.Left, Rect1.Top, Rect1.Width, Rect1.Height*2)
```

When using classes, if one wants an object that's slightly different from an existing object, one must consider before mutating the object whether anyone else might want to use the original; if so, one must make a copy of it and then make the desired changes to the copy.  With structs, there's no such restriction.

A simple way to think of value types is to regard every assignment operation as making a clone of the original, but in a way that's considerably cheaper than cloning a class type.  If one would end up cloning a lot of objects as often as one would assign references without cloning, that's a substantial argument in favor of structs.