# Is there a way to return multiple types in a VB .Net function? (not a Tuple, like PHP internal functions)

Tags: .net, vb.net

So you know how PHP internal functions usually return a boolean `FALSE` when a function fails, or some other data type when the function succeeds? Is this possible in VB .Net?

For instance, lets say this simple code here

```
Public Function TrySomething(ByVal Param As String) \\what would go here??
    If Param <> "MAGICWORD" Then
        Return False
    Else
        Return "You Win!"
    End If
End Function
```

You see I want to return a BOOLEAN false when a function fails, and a string when the function works. Any ideas? I've looked everywhere, and when I search for "return multiple types" all I find is Tuple.

Comment: Is there are string need for the 'False' result to be a bool. As Stefan mentions below, you need to mess around with the return type in the calling routine.  For the above case the simplest might be to return null on 'False'.

Comment: returning false rather than a real value is actually poor practice, and one of the reasons a lot of us don't like php so much. A better solution is to throw an exception instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will Work for you:

```
Public Function TrySomething(ByVal Param As String) As Object
If Param <> "MAGICWORD" Then
    Return False
Else
    Return "You Win!"
End If
End Function
```

You can check the values like this:

```
 Dim a As Boolean = TrySomething("")
 Dim b As String = TrySomething("MAGICWORD")
```

Comment: The code has a flaw: what will happen when executing dim a2 as boolean = TrySomething( "I want to raise an exception")?

Answer (score 8):

You could use an object as Dan says. But then you have to check for the returned type in the calling routine.

```
Sub Checkit()
    Dim ret As Object = TrySomething("MAGICWORD")
    If TypeOf ret Is Boolean Then
        'dosomething
        MsgBox("Nope!")
    End If
    If TypeOf ret Is String Then
        'dosomethingelse
        MsgBox("Yes, you won!")
    End If

End Sub

Public Function TrySomething(ByVal Param As String) As Object
    If Param <> "MAGICWORD" Then
        Return False
    Else
        Return "You Win!"
    End If
End Function
```

I would not go that way, I would create a structure or class to handle exactly what I wanted instead. Like this:

```
Sub Checkit()
    Dim ret As TryReturnStruct = TrySomething("MAGICWORD")
    MsgBox(ret.Message)
    If ret.Success Then
        MsgBox("Do you want to play again?")
    End If
End Sub

Structure TryReturnStruct
    Public Success As Boolean
    Public Message As String
End Structure

Public Function TrySomething(ByVal Param As String) As TryReturnStruct
    Dim ret As New TryReturnStruct

    If Param <> "MAGICWORD" Then
        ret.Success = False
        ret.Message = "Nope, not yet!"
    Else
        ret.Success = True
        ret.Message = "You Win!"
    End If
    Return ret
End Function
```

Comment: Bout to give this a shot. If it works, I'd say this is the answer. I'm getting tired of checking object types.

Comment: Looks like it may be much the same either way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898443/vb-net-is-using-structures-considered-nasty
Except if you use the object class you don't have to declare a structure. Hmm...upvotes all-around.

Answer (score 2):

You can return an object. In VBA you would return a variant to handle such a situation.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to return several values, create a class for the result.
(I'm a C# guy, so no VB, sorry)

```
// A generic result type.
class Result<T> 
{
   public bool Success { get; set; }
   public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

However, most times when you have "result value or failure" as the outcome of a call you should probably just treat the failure as an exception.

```
string MyMethod(string arg)
{
    if (arg != "Magic")
       throw new ArgumentException("Argument was incorrect", "arg");
    return "Hello " + arg;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I were to use a class, I would make it something like this:

```
Public Class MyReturnType
    Private _value As Object
    Private _valueType As Type

    Public Sub New()
        _value = New Object
        _valueType = GetType(Object)
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(value As Object, valueType As Type)
        _value = value
        _valueType = valueType
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property Value As Object
        Get
            Return _value
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property ValueType As Type
        Get
            Return _valueType
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Then you can:

```
Public Function TrySomething(ByVal Param As String) As MyReturnType
    If Param <> "MAGICWORD" Then
        Return New MyReturnType(False, GetType(Boolean))
    Else
        Return New MyReturnType("You Win!", GetType(String))
    End If
End Function
```

And all is good:

```
Sub DoSomethingWithReturnValue()
    Dim returnValue As MyReturnType = TrySomething("MAGICWORD")
    If returnValue.ValueType = GetType(Boolean) Then
        DoSomethingWithABoolean(CType(returnValue.Value, Boolean))
    Else
        DoSomethingWithAString(CType(returnValue.Value, String))
    End If
End Sub
```

Personally however I do not think this is good design. If you need to handle multiple types, use overloads, or multiple functions. In your case it's a simple "value or bust" situation, so I would just throw an exception and handle it, which is what you should be doing in .NET.